ArcGIS Pro Tool parameters - choosing fields from many polygons
I want users to be able to choose many polygons and a field from each polygon. Picture below is how the tool looks now for a 2 polygon example explained below.
I have tried
1 polygon - Works

all fields for that polygon appear in the InField drop down box
I can use Python to get those values and be on my way

2 polygons - Does not work

all fields for the first polygon appear in the InField drop down box
no fields from the second polygon appear in the InField drop down
I don't see how to select one polygon at a time anyway

Many polygons and their fields - the dream

For each polygon, users would select a polygon and then one of its fields

Is this possible, maybe in a different way?



You need to create a value table parameter, in ArcPro you can set it like this:

The interface would look like this:


Fantastic. I knew it must be possible. Unfortunately I need to go and fight ICT to get the upgrade to 3.2. Otherwise, spot on help.
